# how to redirect the old domain to the new domain not affect keyword rankings?

Tags: redirect, dns, keyword-search

How to redirect the old domain (http://www.maylocnuocsonha.com/) to the new domain (http://sonhavietnam.vn/) not affect keyword rankings ?

Please guide ! Thank